# jQuery text() not comparing to an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare

So not the first time i've had this problem. I have a simple array 'exceptions'. For simplicity I have reduced it to contain one value until I solve the issue. Onclicking an 'img' get the 'text' next to the image, or the text of the span tag container. 
For example:

```
<span> text + <img class=exit src=images/cross-icon.png alt=some_text> </span>
```

Then compare the text or 'var t' with the only element in my array exceptions 'exceptions[0]'

```
$('#categories').on('click','img',function() {
var q = $(this).parent();
var t = q.text();
loop( t );
});

function loop(param) {
// alert( param + ' ' + exceptions[0] ); //alerts the exact same value
// alert( jQuery.type(param) +' '+ $.type(exceptions[0]) ); //alerts string
//above shows that there the same type and value.
    for (var i=0;i<exceptions.length;i++) { 
        if (exceptions[i] == param) {
            alert('works!');
        }
    }
}
```

It is not alerting 'Works!'. Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in `exceptions`? Do they have the same casing? Is there any leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: try stripping any possible whitespace with $.trim(param)

Comment: Please tell us what is in `exceptions`.

Comment: I think @flem/@scrappedcola are correct, quick js fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jz5rP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New edit: just replace `var t = q.text();` with `var t = $.trim(q.text());` as @adeneo suggests:

```
$('#categories').on('click','img',function() {
var q = $(this).parent();
var t = $.trim( q.text() );
loop( t );
});

function loop(param) {
// alert( param + ' ' + exceptions[0] ); //alerts the exact same value
// alert( jQuery.type(param) +' '+ $.type(exceptions[0]) ); //alerts string
//above shows that there the same type and value.
    for (var i=0;i<exceptions.length;i++) { 
        if (exceptions[i] == param) {
            alert('works!');
        }
    }
}
```

---

Right answer by @adeneo, yet this is one step to debug this kind of bugs: http://jsfiddle.net/AstDerek/X2Cej/

---

Much hated first answer:

Your logic seems wrong, `q` is an image, `t = q.text()` is empty

Comment: q is not an image. It is the parent of the image.

Comment: q is the span, not the image

Comment: No, `q` is the `img` tag's parent.

Comment: Also, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Calm down people, too much hate. You'd better try to answer the question, not hating my mistake

Comment: @AstDerek We're not hating. 1) It's a comment, 2) It's incorrect so it's not even an answer. It's just a false statement. It should be removed.

Comment: @War10ck, if I really thought there was a problem with the logic, then why would that be a comment and not an answer?